# Find product objects where the product names contains a searchstring AND ignores case sensivity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax search function which is triggered by an onkeydown event. The server returns Json objects (Product objects) from the productcontroller, back to the view.

The contains search works just fine except for one big problem. It's case sensitive. A user should be able to enter both lower, upper and mixed lower and upper cases and still get the same result. I know that the problem lies in the controller method, which looks like this at the moment:

```
public JsonResult TextChangeEventSearch(string searchString)
    {
        var products = _productRepository.GetAll().ToList();   

        //This line right here performs the search, but I want it ignore case sensitivity as well.
        var result = products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(searchString));


        var jsonList = result.Select(p => new
        {
            Name = p.Name,
            Status = p.Status,
            Genre = p.Category.Name,
            Value = p.Id.ToString(),
            Warehouse = p.Stock
        });


        return Json(jsonList.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I'm actually after the stringcomparison.ordinalignorecase method and I've been trying to combine it within the result linq query line. But there's always an issue with the syntax when I'm trying to do that, so I'm definitively doing something wrong.

Any thoughts, suggestions and explanation would be appreciated.

So how do I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
products.Where(p => p.Name.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

or wrap it to an extension.

Comment: Worked the very first time. Thanks!